# MATLAB - How to import and plot data from a .mat file to x and y variables?

Tags: matlab, loops

I have a problem that I thought I knew how I can fix, but apparently I failed ..

I got a `.mat` file that I created. It has two columns and 25 rows of numbers. I would like to do a loop to get each value in the first column and put it in the X value, and the second column in the Y value. I then need to plot the points on the graph.

I know how to do the loop, and the plotting .. but I failed to extract the data and put them in X and Y values.

This is my trial code:

```
        load figureinfo.mat
        for K=1:25
            x=X(:,K) ~~ I remember that the code looks something like that to extract ..
            y=Y(:,K)
            plot(x,y,'o')
            hold on
        end
```

How do I get the data and put it in X and Y?

In addition, where is "ROWS" in `(:,b)`? `b=Columns`, but where do I put the rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
load figureinfo.mat; %# assume this contains a matrix called figureinfo
X = figureinfo(:,1); %# numbers from all rows, column 1, into X
Y = figureinfo(:,2); %# numbers from all rows, column 2, into Y
plot(x,y,'o');
```

Or more simply,

```
load figureinfo.mat;
plot(figureinfo(:,1), figureinfo(:,2), 'o');
```

If you don't know the name of the matrix in your `.mat` file, I recommend:

```
clear %# clear all variables from workspace
load figureinfo.mat;
whos
```

which will show the the name, size, and datatype of whatever you just loaded.

If you really want to extract the data in a loop, you have two options:

```
load figureinfo.mat; %# assume this contains a matrix called figureinfo
X = [];
Y = [];
for ctr = 1:length(figureinfo)
    X = [X figureinfo(ctr,1)];
    Y = [Y figureinfo(ctr,2)];
end
```

or (faster because it doesn't keep reallocating `X` and `Y`)

```
load figureinfo.mat; %# assume this contains a matrix called figureinfo
X = zeros(length(figureinfo),1);
Y = zeros(length(figureinfo),1);
for ctr = 1:length(figureinfo)
    X(ctr) = figureinfo(ctr,1);
    Y(ctr) = figureinfo(ctr,2);
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much .. Im getting `??? Undefined variable figureinfo.` .. Is this because I may have created an incorrect mat file ?? I only have two columns, and they have numbers .. looks valid right ?

Comment: I assumed that the variable in your `.mat` file was called `figureinfo`.  That's a bad assumption on my part.  Try doing `clear; load figureinfo.mat; whos` to find the real name of the matrix.

Comment: Ahhh that worked, thanks !!!!! :)  One more thing, if I want to do a loop to extract each value row by row and plot it, where do I put "K" that in (:,2) ??

Comment: I edited to add the loop info.  The rule to remember is that the indeces are `row,column`.  The `:` operator pulls a whole row/column out for you, so that you don't have to write the loop yourself.  In your initial example, `x = X(:,K)` means 'pull the numbers in all rows, K'th column from X and put them in x`.

Comment: Actually, can you tell me what's in `figureinfo.mat`?  I assumed it was one matrix, but in looking at your question again I realize that it actually has two matrices X and Y.  Is that right, and what are their sizes?

Comment: I just got the loop to work. For your question, the first column has X coordinates and the second Column has the Y coordinates .. Regarding the loop, all I had to do is put a `pause(0.5)` and `hold on` .. while having `K` (the function of the loop) instead of `:` then the points plot as needed :)

Comment: Cool, glad it's working.  You might try `drawnow()` instead of `pause` to make the graph update.